# Cisco ASA, OCSP

Tags: cisco, ocsp

I have successfully configured OpenSSL OCSP responder with this hierarchy:
**RootCA > OCSP responder (signed by RootCA).**

I have deployed a trustpoint (named **RootCA**) into the ASA with the RootCA public key. So I expect that ASA will be trusted to OCSP, because it's trusted by RootCA which has a signed OCSP key. But seems it is not. Due to VPN client connection I have.

`CRYPTO_PKI: Blocking chain callback called for OCSP response <...> status: 2`

I get the above debug message, which indicates a problem with the certificate signer, according to 
[BRKSEC-3053](https://clnv.s3.amazonaws.com/2015/usa/pdf/BRKSEC-3053.pdf)

So, I imported the OCSP key into a separate trustpoint (named **OCSP**) and created a certificate map with an overriding OCSP rule. The revocation check hierarchy now looks like this:

**VPN client > RootCA > certificate map > OCSP responder.**

With that scheme, the OCSP responses are trusted and revocation check completed successfully.

My questions are:

1. Do we really need a separate trustpoint for OCSP signing key?
2. Or this is expected behavior with OCSP responder implementation in OpenSSL?
3. Or maybe I have missed something important?

Thank you!